# Ajax call on slideToggle

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting some data from the server via Ajax call on button click, but I would like to get the data only when the drop-down goes down, would like to avoid the call when the drop-down goes back up.

Here is my jquery

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
$('.test').slideToggle('slow');
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: /testUrl.php,
   success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
 });  
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  if (!$('.test').is(:visible))
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: /testUrl.php,
      success: function(result) {
      alert(result);
    });  
  $('.test').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  var $test = $('.test');
  $test.slideToggle('slow');
  if (!$test.is(':visible')) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: /testUrl.php,
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });  
  }
});
```